# Is it possible to access a just specified property?

Tags: javascript, properties

I'm using trying improve the readability of some code i'm writing. I pass an array of values to a function and want to be able to extract each. I'd like to check that the array is the expected size.

```
function useData(data) {
    if (data.length != Data.Size) {
        // ERROR
    }

    var name = data[Data.Indexes.NAME];
    var age = data[Data.Indexes.AGE];
    var weight = data[Data.Indexes.WEIGHT];
}
```

I want to know how many properties are in `Data.Indexes`, i've tried the following two methods,

```
var Data = {
    Indexes : {
        NAME : 0,
        AGE : 1,
        WEIGHT : 2
    },
    Size : Objects.keys(Indexes).length  // Doesn't work.
};
Data.Size2 = Object.keys(Data.Indexes).length;  // Works.
```

Can I find the size of `Indexes` whilst still inside `Data`?

Comment: Have you tried `Size : Objects.keys(this.Indexes).length` inside Data?

Comment: There seems to be something you're not telling us. If the code that defines `Data` looks exactly like that, then you know the size of `Indexes` is 3, and you could simply write `Size: 3`. If `Indexes` is in fact defined by some other means, say from a variable, then you could inspect that variable `var Data = { Indexes: myIndexes, Size: Object.keys(myIndexes).length`. (But to answer your question, no, I don't believe you can access a property of an object inside the statement defining it)

Comment: @David Hedlund I'm trying to avoid bugs being introduced if `Data.Indexes` is changed to add or remove a property. I've been burned by things like that in every language i've ever used!

Comment: @artm Yes, I did try using `this.Indexes`. I got the following error `TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead has type undefined.`

Comment: @PhilWright: No chance of rewriting your code to make `Size` a function, then? `Size: function() { return Object.keys(this.Indexes).length; }`. That of course means you'll have to call that function whenever you're checking the size.

Comment: @PhilWright I have updated my answer with two links.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Making size a function did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Size`-property a function returning the number of properties in Indexes like so:

```
var Data = {
    Indexes : {
       NAME : 0,
       AGE : 1,
       WEIGHT : 2
    },
    Size : function() {return Object.keys(this.Indexes).length}
};
```

Now you can **call** it inside function `useData()`:

```
function useData(data) {
    if (data.length != Data.Size()) {/* ERROR */}
    /* ... */
}
```

A second way makes `Data.Size` a `getter`-function. That way it's protected against overwriting:

```
var Data = {
    Indexes : { /* ... */ },
    get Size() {return Object.keys(this.Indexes).length
};
```

The getter is executed each time you **refer** to it:

```
function useData(data) {
    if (data.length != Data.Size) {/* ERROR */}
    /* ... */
}
Data.Size = 55; // nothing happens
```

**Update**: These ways doesn't protect Data.Indexes against changes. If you need that, have a look at [Object.seal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) and [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).